# Disable enter for submitting comments

Tags: script, comments, greasemonkey

### About

This user script disables the default behavior of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key [submitting a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/63303/why-can-you-type-new-lines-in-comments-if-they-are-never-rendered). With this script installed, you must explicitly click the Add Comment button to submit your comment.

[image]

### Source

If you have Firefox+GreaseMonkey, Opera, or Google Chrome, try this GreaseMonkey script that will disable enter in comments.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable Enter key on comments on Stack Exchange.
// @namespace      http://networkpx.googlecode.com
// @description    Disable Enter key on comments on Stack Exchange.
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include        http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include        http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML = '$(document).delegate(".comments-link, .comment-edit", "click", function(e) { \
  var events = $(this).closest("td").find("textarea[name=comment]").data("events"); \
  var makeShift = { handler: function(e) { e.shiftKey = true; } }; \
  events.keyup.splice(0, 0, makeShift); \
  events.keypress.splice(0, 0, makeShift); \
});';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

### Installation

[Click here to download this script](https://gist.github.com/raw/735127/6e6d0b1ac07d5d1297e09976e12b6590082c3ff6/enter-comments.user.js).

See the script info page for step-by-step install instructions

https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: P.S. This works on Firefox with GreaseMonkey - I tested it.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks, now it also prevents the Enter key from posting the comment while editing too!

Comment: please you didn't include stackapps in your script.

Comment: I've a weird issue with this on Chrome 35. When this script is enabled and I click "add comment", nothing happens except going to the top of the page...I don't see why that should happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I can confirm. brasofolio's version seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

I created another version of the script modifying:

- Shift + Enter submits the comment.
- Changed `@include`s for `@match`es using another domain pattern.
- Used [another script injection technique](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a).
- Tried to solve instances where the script would produce an error wrapping the block where the error occurs within a `try{} catch(){}`. Then I discovered that adding a timeout made the script work in pages where it was failing. I'll leave both for now, but probably the timeout suffices.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Disable Enter key on comments on Stack Exchange.
// @namespace       https://stackapps.com/a/4910
// @version         1.1
// @description     Disable Enter key on comments on Stack Exchange.
// @homepage        https://stackapps.com/q/2061
// @icon            https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xzO1.png
// @match           *://*.askubuntu.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.mathoverflow.net/questions*
// @match           *://*.serverfault.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.stackapps.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.stackexchange.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.superuser.com/questions*
// ==/UserScript==

function inject() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i ) {
        if ( typeof(arguments[i]) == 'function' ) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.textContent = '(' + arguments[i].toString() + ')(jQuery)';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
}

inject(function ($) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        // Run only on individual posts
        if( ( StackExchange.options.routeName.indexOf('Questions/Show') === -1 ) ) 
            return;

        $(document).delegate(".comments-link, .comment-edit", "click", function(e) {        
            var events = $(this).closest("td").find("textarea[name=comment]").data("events");
            var makeShift = { handler: function(e) { 
                if( e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey )
                    e.shiftKey = false; 
                else
                    e.shiftKey = true; 
            } };
            try {
                events.keyup.splice(0, 0, makeShift);
                events.keypress.splice(0, 0, makeShift);
            }
            catch (evt) {
                console.error('Disable Enter key on comments on Stack Exchange failed to load');
            }
        });
    }, 500 );
});
```

#### [Install link](https://gist.github.com/raw/a539c1905608b253fcb6/DisableEnterKeyOnComments.user.js)

Comment: Looks this works unreliably. It worked when I tried to comment this answer. Then it didn't with the OP. 
Edit: And now it failed again here too. Weird
Edit2: I was mistaken. It doesn't work for comments and all. (I was typing into the answer field by accident)