# SE Comment Preview - An attempt to add real-time previewing for comments

Tags: script, comments

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot showing new preview below comment entry textbox]

### About

This script creates a new live preview directly beneath any comment you compose or edit.

When writing a comment with a lot of formatting, especially one containing some mathematical formulas, I often found myself pasting it into the "new answer" editor at the bottom of the page to see if everything was rendering properly. This script has made writing such comments a much nicer experience for me so I hope others enjoy it as well.

It works on all Stack Exchange sites (as far as I know). If the site happens to use MathJax for math formatting then the math is rendered in the new preview just like when you're writing an answer, if a little more slowly.

Check out the [GitHub page](https://github.com/szego/SE-CommentPreview) for more info including a list of known issues.

### Installation

In Chrome, install Tampermonkey then click **[here](https://github.com/szego/SE-CommentPreview/raw/master/comment-preview.user.js)**.

This script does not work in Firefox (yet?).

### Code

Markdown is processed using [my fork](https://github.com/szego/marked/tree/disable-elements) of [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked). Math removal/replacement is handled using Stack Exchange's methods. These are coodinated with marked using [Megh Parikh's implementation](https://github.com/meghprkh/markdown-mathjax). See [the source code](https://github.com/szego/SE-CommentPreview/blob/master/comment-preview.user.js) for more info.

If you're interested, there is also an experimental (buggy) version of this script which uses Pagedown instead of marked for Markdown processing: [SE Comment Preview - Paged!](https://github.com/szego/SE-CommentPreview/tree/pagedown-for-markdown)

The Paged! version of the script only works on SE sites that use MathJax, but on those sites the new live comment previews behave very similarly to the built-in question/answer editors.

Comment: This may conflict with other extensions. For example, the preview is removed when the return key is pressed (and the comment is >14 characters long), so it doesn't play well with [Disable enter for submitting comments](http://stackapps.com/q/2061/36263).

Comment: When certain characters (`<`, `>`, `&`) are inside code blocks (text surrounded by backticks), they appear as the associated html entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`) instead of the character that they are (and will be in the actual comment) in the preview.

Comment: Also, it seems marked is throwing `Uncaught Error: Infinite loop on byte: 10` when a new line (entered by pasting something with multiple lines, or pressing Shift+Enter) is in the comment field.

Comment: The preview also doesn't show that urls will be automatically converted from `http://domain.tld/path/to/page` to a link that doesn't show the protocol like http://domain.tld/path/to/page.